# 'Who' and 'That' are not always interchangeable

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

When using relative clauses, we encounter two types: *defining*  and *non-defining*. We use commas with the former and not with the latter.

> We know a lot of people who live in London.

> John, who speaks French and Italian, works as a tourist guide.

In the first sentence, we can interchange *who* with *that*. In the second one, however, we can't because it's *non-defining*, **right?**

Comment: Yes, your logic looks OK to me.

Comment: @user405662 I have a Cambridge book which states that. I just want to make sure there is not exceptions. The name of the book is *English Grammar In Use with Answers: A Self-study Reference and Practice Book for Intermediate Students of English* by Raymond Murphy, page 190.

Comment: How can there be exceptions to a rule that says something is not always true?!

Comment: You are right. Non-defining _that_ relatives are extremely rare and really only marginally present in Standard English.

Comment: I would say you can't exchange *who* with *that* in the first sentence. *That* is not used for people. For a sentence "There is a wolf who lives in the forest" it might be OK, but I'd be more likely to use *which.*

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's "which", not "that", which is not used for people. "That" is fine for any noun whatever it means. What authority claims otherwise?

Comment: @RosieF What authority claims *that* is fine?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Same book I've mentioned. *That* can be used for both things and people but not always, as I mentioned, they aren't always interchangeable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Fowler, MEU, 2nd ed., s.v. **which, that, who**, sect. 1. (A) of *which* and *that*, *which* is appropriate to non-defining and *that* to defining clauses; (B) of *which* and *who*, *which* belongs to things, and *who* to persons; (C) of *who* and *that*, *who* suits particular persons, and *that* generic persons.

Comment: @RosiefF If *that* is used for generic people, then it's used in *defining* clauses because we have to specify what we're talking about, it's generic. *A man that slept on the street*. Therefore, I think (C) is a consequence of this usage.

Comment: @Nameless I think your question has been adequately answered. Note, though, that in integrated relatives there is a preference for "who" when the relativised element is subject and for the non-_wh_ type elsewhere, e.g. "the boy (that) they found hiding in the cupboard"